# Javascript - Stop all functions from executing

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in progamming and just wrote my first game with HTML, CSS and vanilla JavaScript. It is working fine but now I am facing an issue while trying to implement a restart-function. 
I found similar questions and tried a lot but couldn't find a way to solve this:
I wrapped the whole game in a function and added an event listener to a button to start the game:

```
game() { /*game code*/ }
gameButton.addEventListener("click", game);
```

Inside the code I got multiple functions and eventListeners. There are three ways to "die" and get an Game Over-message. This is when the game button reappears. However, when you click it, the game()-function is still running and the game isn't working, the way it should anymore. I tried to figure out how to stop the whole game-function in case one of these events happens but without success.

So, for example: if you click at the wrong place, a failed-function gets triggered and your score will be decreased by 1. If your score is below 1, you die and the game is over:

```
function failed() {

    let x = parseInt(score.innerText) - 1;
    score.innerText = x.toString();
    if (x < 1) {
      gameOverText.style.display = "block";
    }
```

How I can I stop the game()-function from here?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It depends on what the `game()` function is doing. You can use `clearTimeout()` and `clearInterval()` to stop timers.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the actual code and design. But the easiest way is a boolean.  and in your methods check to make sure it is still running

```
var isActive = true
function failed() {
  if (!isActive) return
  ...
```

so when the game is over, you set isActive to false

Comment: It would be more efficient to prevent the function from ever getting called, but this method is foolproof.

Comment: @D.Pardal There are better solutions, but without seeing all the code it is impossible to give some of those. ;)

Comment: Thank you both very much! It worked perfectly and fixed the problems! I really appreciate your fast help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to attach/remove listener based on event output. Or you can check for condition and return early

**pseudo code:**

```
const game = () => {
    // Do something here

    if(isDisabled) {
        return 
    }

    // OR

    if(something_to_stop) {
        detachListeners()
    }
}
function attachListeners() {
    gameButton.addEventListener("click", game);
}
function detachListeners() {
    gameButton.removeListener("click", game);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Using a game-over-boolean that gets checked in all my methods did the trick. It is set to true in a game-over-function, which also removes all the active listeners and clears the intervalls and timeouts.